# Where click once get the files that adds in the application files folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

When deploying a ClickOnce from the VS a folder is created under bin/$(configuration) and the name of this folder is app.publish.
Inside that now, there is an other folder called 'Application Files' and inside that there are all the version folders with the required dlls and exe for the application.

The question is: Where does the ClickOnce gets the files to add them to the version folder? And most important when this process is made?

Thanks,
GM

**UPDATE #1**

The issue though is that i am obfuscating some of my dlls but the published files are not the correct ones. The dll i obfuscate is obfuscated in Release folder but not in the published folder.
The obfuscation is made in .csproj with postbuild commands.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can read the official documentation.

When you create the list, the file will be copied.

[DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019)

### How ClickOnce deployment works

The core ClickOnce deployment architecture is based on two XML manifest files: an application manifest and a deployment manifest. The files are used to describe where the ClickOnce applications are installed , how they are updated, and when they are updated.

#### Deploy ClickOnce applications

After it is created, the deployment manifest is copied to the deployment location. This can be a Web server, network file share, or media such as a CD. The application manifest and all the application files are also copied to a deployment location that is specified in the deployment manifest. This can be the same as the deployment location, or it can be a different location. When using the **Publish Wizard** in Visual Studio, the copy operations are performed automatically.

Are there plug-ins or reference files in your assembly, you should add them in the [application file], as shown below:

[image]

In the above interface, change the required file release status to "include".

[image]

In the above interface, copy the required files to the output directory and change it to "Always copy", so that you can ensure that your DLL or some reference files can be released with your program.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
Please check UPDATE #1

Comment: You could try to set it as Copy always and operate as content.

Comment: Thanks 'Jiale Xue - MSFT'.

The issue though is that i am obfuscating my application by adding this code at the end of .csproj: **.dll" ReferenceFolders="$(TargetDir)" /> **.dll;" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)">

But the published files are not the correct ones. The dll i obfuscate is obfuscated in Release folder but not in the published folder.